# Dynamic ng-model with checkbox in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object like as below with name **$scope.permissions**

```
{
    admission:{create:false,delete:false,read:false,update:false},
    student:{forDelete:false,read:false,viewPhone:false},
    course:{create:false,delete:false,read:false,update:false},
    teacher:{create:false,read:false,contact:false}
}
```

I want to make dynamic **ng-model** in each row like as

```
<div ng-repeat="(permissionName, permission) in permissions">
      {{permissionName}} |
      <label ng-repeat="(k,v) in permission">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.k">
            {{ k }}
       </label>
      <button ng-click="updatePermission(permission)">Update</button>
</div>
```

When user will click on update button it will pass the student object with checkbox's value true or false.

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: and your question?

Comment: I want to make dynamic ng-model in each row from my $scope.permissions object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first loop over permissions object with `(key, value)` format of `ng-repeat`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="(permissionName, permission) in permissions">
    {{permissionName}} |
    <label ng-repeat="(k,v) in permission">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission[k]"> {{ k }}
    </label>
    <button ng-click="updatePermission(permission)">Update</button>
</div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/byCg6PcHuwuWxaKxr2iK?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. The render input is not fixed (create, read, update, delete). a student key can have any number of key-value pair.

Comment: Can you elaborate it please